# Excel Ribbons Doesn't work after file rename

Tags: excel, ribbon, vba

Heyy
I have been creating Macros and then adding them to the customized ribbons on excel (2010). The problem I have is that each time I rename the original file (save as) that i created the macros and ribbon in and then click on the ribbon/macro it automatically opens up the original file for it to work on the new save as file. if i remove file from original path and then open again the renamed file and run macro using ribbon it doesn't run it gives me error file not found.

i have exported customized ribbon ui and when i open it using notepad++ i can see hardcoded paths of original file
is there anyway to resolve this?? to rename those ribbons everytime i save file with different name or at different path....

Answer (score 1):

Use the Custom UI Editor from here:
http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2010/08/10/23248.aspx

There is a Microsoft guide here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx

When actually coding the macros and ribbons, avoid hardcoding the names and it will work perfectly. Here is the code I use in one of my macro files for an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="refunds" label="Refunds/Returns" >
        <group id="financeRefund" label="Refunds &amp; Returns" >
          <button id="refresh" visible="true" size="large" 
                  label="Refresh Front Page" keytip="R" 
                  screentip="Refresh the frontpage without clearing the data in the data sheet." 
                  onAction="refreshfp" imageMso="RecurrenceEdit" />
          <button id="new" visible="true" size="large" 
                  label="Update Data" keytip="S" 
                  screentip="Pulls in new data from the live sheet, clearing any changes made to the current     data sheet." 
                  onAction="updateData" 
imageMso="ExportSharePointList" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Hope this helps